# Apache + PHP (multi version) + multi sites (with different PHP versions) + user access setup

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi, multisite

I was searching the internet looking for solution, unfortunately none of those was helpful.

I am trying to achive the following:

On Linux Ubuntu 20.04 setup several sites. Each site may have different PHP version. Also users of each site must not be able to read/write files on other sites. Each site should have own group/user.

I see the solution this way (and was trying this way):

- to create different folders with different group/users (site1/site1, site2/site2)
- install Apache, PHP as FCGI
- enable MPM module to be able to run script on behalf of different user on each site

What I could do so far. I could install Apache + PHP (+FCGI) with different versions. So far it was ok, no problem.
Then I need to separate users I enabled MPM modules of Apache. The best result I could get is to run PHP script as if on behalf of different users. But when PHP script is trying to create a file in the same folder I can see the owner/group as www-data. So security issues are not resolved.
I not not sure that enabling MPM is working as it should.

Since there is a lot of work done, I didn't want to show all long list of commands here. I hope someone could advise the correct guide I could look at.

If not helpful I'll show all here

UPD 1: (I coudn't find a proper way to show code in reply comment, so I do this way)

```
sudo apt-get install apache2

sudo apt-get install php7.4

sudo apt-get install libapache2-mpm-itk

sudo useradd -m --shell /bin/bash --home /home/u-site1 u-site1

sudo passwd u-site1

sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.local.conf

-- start of content
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.local
    ServerAdmin info@site1.local
    DocumentRoot /home/u-site1/site1.local/html
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1.local.log combined
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1.local-error.log
    <IfModule itk.c>
        AssignUserID u-site1 u-site1
    </IfModule>
    <Directory "/home/u-site1/site1.local/html">
        Options All -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
-- end of content

sudo mkdir -p /home/u-site1/site1.local/html

sudo a2ensite site1.local.conf

sudo vi /home/u-site1/site1.local/html/index.php

-- start of content
site1.local
<?php
$sFilePath = __DIR__ . "/new.file";
$bRes = file_put_contents($sFilePath, "TEST");
if($bRes === false)
    echo "<pre>", var_export(error_get_last(), 1), "</pre>";
phpinfo();
-- end of content

sudo chown -R u-site1:u-site1 /home/u-site1/site1.local

sudo chmod 755 /home/u-site1/site1.local

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: Hi. You want to setup apache virtual hosts with multiple users?

Comment: I think you should take a look into the `apache2-mpm-itk` module. As far as I understood you want to run each vhost as different user. https://serverok.in/apache-virtualhost-separate-user-with-mpm-itk

Comment: @Monnomcjo, yes

Comment: @steven, thank you for the link. Unfortunately, following instruction on that guide I have results different from what I have expected.
I show here dump of my commands, so you can assess:

Comment: @steven, after I did as per link you provided I wondered who will be the owner of newly created file. I was www-data, not the u-test1 user. The file will be created if I give permission o+w to /home/u-site1/site1.local/html. Otherwise permission is denied. As I see mpm-itk is not working as expected or am I doing something wrong?
Please, see in UPD1 above in question